# PHP - changing ownership of a process while running

Tags: php, ownership

I have a PHP script that I need to run as root from the command line.

After the script completes some critical operations (that require root access) I would like to change the owner of the process to 'nobody'.

Is that possible with PHP? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change user/group ids with the following functions:

[posix_setgid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-setgid.php)

[posix_setuid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-setuid.php)

[posix_setegid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-setegid.php)

[posix_seteuid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-seteuid.php)

If you need to change the group, you'll want to perform that first.

Answer (score 0):

No, script cannot change ownership explicitly to root.